# Why count query runs slower in less data than more data in MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have two tables, user and sku_pro, the count query in two tables as follow

```

mysql> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE user.is_active = 1 \G;

COUNT(id): 239568

1 row in set (0.20 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sku_pro WHERE is_agent=1 \G;

COUNT(id): 1254286

1 row in set (0.11 sec)

```

user has 61 columns, run show table status in user table, the result is

`mysql> show table status like 'user' \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: user
         Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 239606
 Avg_row_length: 252
    Data_length: 60483836
Max_data_length: 281474976710655
   Index_length: 34577408
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 239623
    Create_time: 2016-08-24 12:01:55
    Update_time: 2016-09-14 10:48:10
     Check_time: 2016-08-24 12:02:04
      Collation: utf8_bin
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:`

sku_pro has 16 columns, run show table status in sku_pro table, the result is

`mysql> show table status like 'sku_pro' \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: sku_pro
         Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Fixed
           Rows: 1281901
 Avg_row_length: 53
    Data_length: 67940753
Max_data_length: 14918173765664767
   Index_length: 52064256
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 1988051
    Create_time: 2016-09-09 14:06:37
    Update_time: 2016-09-14 10:19:39
     Check_time: 2016-09-09 14:06:44
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.01 sec)`

I don't know Why count(id) in user is slower than count(id) in sku_pro.

Comment: First thing I'd do is compare the EXPLAIN plan for each query. Are both the `user.is_active` and `sku_pro.is_agent` columns indexed?

Comment: @Phil there are not indexed. Maybe I have find the reason.  The row_format in user table is Dynamic,  but in sku_pro table is Fixed. I takes more time to find the value of user.is_active than sku_pro.is_agent.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Caching.

**Really long answer:**

**First some notes**

`COUNT(ID)` requires counting the number of *non-NULL* IDs.  Don't use that construct unless you really need to avoid NULLs.

Now, I'll look at your particular queries, both of which look like

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE flag=1;
```

As you mentioned, the tables are 'big'.  This implies that the data/index blocks needed may or may not cached in RAM.  This one issue can easily make a query run 10x faster/slower.  Try this:  Restart mysql, run the query twice.  The second run will be 10x faster than the first.

I am assuming you have the "Query cache" turned off.  If it were in use, that would add a big wrinkle.

**Dissecting your query**

To optimize your query, you need this composite index:

```
INDEX(flag, id) -- with the columns in that order.
```

Given that, the query will be performed entirely in the index.  We call that a "covering" index.  (MyISAM and InnoDB act the same here.)  Since you are specifying a value for `flag`, it will only do a "range" scan over part of the index.  (Hence, we cannot easily say how many disk blocks need to be touched.)

If you have just `INDEX(flag)`, the optimizer will probably ignore it and do a full table scan.

A full table scan (if the table is not cached) will run in a time proportional to the table size (`Data_length`).

**InnoDB**

This discussion assumes *no* `WHERE` clause.  And using `COUNT(*)`.

(Excuse me while I give some irrelevant info about InnoDB.)

MyISAM keeps an exact count of the number of rows in each table.  Hence, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myisam_table` with no `WHERE` is always nearly instantaneous.  (This *one* query is about the only one for which MyISAM consistently out-performs InnoDB.)

InnoDB, on the other hand, cannot.  This is because different connections can be running different transactions, any of which could be rolled back, thereby messing with any attempt to dead reckon an exact count.  Instead, InnoDB finds the "smallest" index and scans it.

InnoDB keeps an approximate row count, which it derives from a small number of random probes into a BTree.  This number is seen in `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and in `information_schema.TABLES`.  The `avg_row_length` is derived from `Data_length/Rows`, so it is also imprecise.  And both numbers will change from time to time.  (The frequency of changing has changed significantly with recent versions.)

*With* a `WHERE` clause puts the two engines on a very similar footing.  This gets into how indexes work.